# Unit Testing Custom Code Analysis Rules in 2010 - Any Hope

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing, rules

In the past it has been a real PITA to unit test custom Code Analysis rules. I haven't found anything out there that shows the situation to be any different in 2010, but I'm not giving up. If anyone knows if this is "possible" in 2010 please respond - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Johnathan,

I should've posted this sooner...I eventually figured this out in VS2010, and it's actually quite easy:

http://www.jasonbock.net/JB/Default.aspx?blog=entry.d6f6046800d945e6b94e8d92a4da52c2

Comment: This link is no longer valid.  More helpful to post information inline.

Comment: @TroyParsons this link works fine for me. It still seems a lot like a 'link-only' answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to do it the old fashioned way.

1. Create a test project that demonstrates all the issues you are supposed to catch.
2. Create a test harness that executes MSBuild against your test project and captures the output.
3. Parse the results looking for the errors you intended.